# How to handle system Dark mode in QML

Tags: macos, qt, qml, darkmode

I'm using QML + Python to create a multi-platform application. Facing a challenge with handling System Dark Mode (not sure if it applies to Windows, but I'm currently using a Mac).

For now I do set Dark / Light mode manually, using property. Is there any way I can detect user's mode and set this value to my property? Or are there any other possible solutions?

```
import QtCore
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    property bool darkMode: false
    
    Text {
        id: textField
        color: {
            switch (darkMode) {
                case true:
                    "white";
                    break;
                case false:
                    "black";
                    break;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are styles in QtQuick that are system theme aware by default. `Material.theme: Material.System` Have a read here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-theme-attached-prop

Comment: @iam_Peter that's a great solution! Just gave it a try. Yet it gives my app more Android-like design, whereas I want it to be more macOS / iOS styled or just native to a platform it is running on. Are there any ways to do it?

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691026/qml-how-to-get-the-system-assigned-text-color-of-a-textfield-at-runtime Works good for my needs.

Comment: As an aside, your code will be cleaner if you learn to use the conditional operator. Replace that switch statement with this: `color: darkMode ? "white" : "black"`